# Unexplained dead lock situation when using static mutex in function

Tags: multithreading, c++11, singleton, mutex

The code below is an extreme simplification of the actual code I'm dealing with. This is just for anyone to be able to reproduce the issue I'm facing.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using std::mutex;
using std::thread;

void Do()
{
   static mutex myMutex;
   static int dataToProtect;
   return;
}

class MyClass
{
   public:
      ~MyClass()
      {
         mythread_.join();
      }


      void RunMyThread()
      {
         mythread_ = thread(&Do);
      }

      static MyClass *Instance()
      {
         static MyClass single;
         return &single;
      }

   private:
      MyClass()
      {}

      std::thread mythread_;
};



int main()
{
   MyClass::Instance()->RunMyThread();
   return 0;
}
```

When complied with gcc on MinGW-w64, the execution gets stuck in:

```
static mutex myMutex;
```

It looks like the combination of the thread and the singleton design create this issue, because if I call Do() without using a thread:

```
  void RunMyThread()
  { 
     // mythread_ = thread(&Do);
     Do();
  }
```

the program executes to the end.
Or, if I get around the singleton design by making the constructor public, and I call RunMyThread() through an instance of MyClass:

```
int main()
{
   // MyClass::Instance()->RunMyThread();
   MyClass o;
   o.RunMyThread();
   return 0;
}
```

the program executes to the end as well.

Now, if I compile the original code at the top with gcc on Linux, there is no issue. The program executes to the end.

I can't figure out what behavior in this code is platform dependent. Any idea?

Comment: Are there two threads stuck, or just one?  Have you examined their stack traces, including disassembly?  And how do you *know* it gets stuck there.  One issue you have is that your `thread` does not finish before the end of `main`, and I believe this results in your behavior being underspecified in the standard...

Comment: @Yakk The thread finishes before the end of main because the main thread is waiting in the MyClass destructor for the child thread. I know that the execution gets stuck in the child thread because when I put break point on "static mutex myMutex" the main thread is already waiting for the child thread at "mythread_.join();" in MyClass destructor. Now, when I try to step over after that point with the debugger the execution gets stuck. Sorry, I don't have the skills to interpreter disassembled code.

Comment: Not the main thread, but the `main` function.  Destruction of function statics occurs after `main` ends.  Thread state and behavior after `main` ends is extremely underspecified in the standard in my experience.  Note that text that looks `like this` means I'm referring to words in code.  `main` as a word-in-code only occurs in C++ for the `main` function.  So "end of `main`" refers to the end of the thing called `main` in your code. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the previous comments/answers, a simple answer to the question is: Allowing a thread to execute after the main function returns is what causes the undefined behavior.
(If code portability is a requirement, this should be avoided.)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by the order that things are cleaned up in the Windows runtime. You can test this by adding an explicit call to your class like this:

```
ShutDown()
{
   mythread_.join();
}
```

Take the join call out of the destructor. Then in your main function:

```
int main()
{
   MyClass::Instance()->RunMyThread();
   MyClass::Instance()->ShutDown();
   return 0;
}
```